# routerLink sometimes does not route to default route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

That is my default route:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
```

When I do routing to default route like by clicking my `next` button `<button [routerLink]="['/']" mat-raised-button color="primary">next</button>` sometime it is does not work.

Always when clicking `next` I am just getting redirected to the current route instead. Then have to click `next` button once again so it brings me to `home`.

Any ideas why does it happen?

**UPDATE**:
Just changed my `button` to `a` - `<a [routerLink]="['/']" mat-raised-button color="primary">next</a>` but still same issue.

**Versions**:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.1
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.1
@angular/cdk                      7.2.1
@angular/cli                      7.2.1
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.23
@angular/material                 7.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.1
@schematics/angular               7.2.1
@schematics/update                0.12.1
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.2
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Answer (score 0):

{
    path: '',
    component: yourComponent
  },
pass like this it will be work

Answer (score 0):

in your routing :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },

    {
        "path": "home",
        "component": yourComponent (for example HomeComponent)
  },
```

and in your HTML:

```
[routerLink]="['/Home']">
```